# PostgreSQL logical replication: initial sync when adding subscriber

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple table I'd like to replicate across a number of servers and I'm considering using the logical replication feature.

From my understanding once a remote server subscribe to the main server's publication it will receive all operations required in order to keep its table up to date.

But what happens with any data already on the master before subscribing?

Is there a mechanism or a best practice to fetch this initial data, or should I just dump and rsync right before creating the subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical replication takes care of initial data with a "initial snapshot" according to [logical replication architecture documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/logical-replication-architecture.html#LOGICAL-REPLICATION-SNAPSHOT)

Comment: Thank you so much pifor, I missed that. Those multi-page manuals are killing me.